# remove what ever comes after “\” using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Anyone would help to figure out how to remove the last few characters in PowerShell, for example:

```
server\instance
```

need to remove `\instance` part to become:

```
server
```

Comment: Do you have anything you have already tried yet? Using a string split on the slash and grabbing the first portion of the array is where I might go with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand, but if service\instance is a string you could do it with

```
"server\instance" -replace "\\.*", ""
```

to replace everything \ and after with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `Split-Path`

## Example

```
Split-Path 'server\instance'
```

## Result

> server

Comment: This is actually the "best" awnser since the builtin cmdlet split-path is made for this by microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Substring` like this:

```
$s = 'server\instance'
$s.Substring(0, $s.IndexOf('\'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
PS C:\> ('server\instance' -split '\\')[0]
server
```